# Lambda function not found while invoke it from python program

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I have created lambda function and tried to invoke it from python program using boto3 API,its failing.

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('lambda','us-east-1')
response = client.invoke(
    FunctionName='arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:025631470700:function:app-test',
    InvocationType='Event',
    LogType='Tail',
    Payload='{"name": "David","status": "Active"}',
    Qualifier='1'
)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ssm-user/test.py", line 11, in <module>
    Qualifier='1'
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 676, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.errorfactory.ResourceNotFoundException: An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the Invoke operation: Function not found: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:025631470700:function:app-test:1
```

Did i miss anything ? Any thoughts, much appreciated

Comment: Are you sure that the function exist and has the name you are using?

Comment: yes, it exists.I just removed the Qualifier parameter and changed the payload to json.dumps({"name": "David","status": "Active"}).It worked.Is it the correct way of sending the payload in bytes ?

Comment: Try `FunctionName='app-test'`. As far as I know, you need the `Name` not `ARN`.

Answer (score 0):

As the user Jens said in the comments, the `FunctionName` argument of the `invoke()` function is not the ARN of the lambda, it's its name. Use this:

```
response = client.invoke(
    FunctionName='app-test',
    InvocationType='Event',
    LogType='Tail',
    Payload='{"name": "David","status": "Active"}',
    Qualifier='1'
)
```